# How to set cell's background in HTML table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to set the background of a cell in HTML table to be like [this](http://i41.tinypic.com/kc17j7.jpg).

- What are my options besides using an image as background ?
- Are there any predefined backgrounds like this ? Maybe dotted, or diagonal lines backgrounds ?
- In case of image background, if I don't know in advance what would be the size of the cell, what image size should I take ? How to make it be repetitive so it would look nice ?

Any HTML/CSS/Javascript/jQuery suggestions are welcome :)

Comment: I wonder if you can take a large swath of the candystripe image and set the whole table's background to it and then just use a solid color where-ever you -don't- want to see the candystripe.  Depending upon what percentage of the cells you want to display that background.  The benefit there being that you'll have less of a problem in the cases that you have a liquid layout instead of fixed width cells, perhaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use a background image for something like that. To make it tiled, you can use the `repeat` property in the CSS definition.

```
td .weird-background { 
    background-image: url('/background.gif');
    background-repeat: repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> What are my options besides using an image as background ?

There might be something in CSS 3 that has very limited browser support.

> In case of image background, if I don't know in advance what would be the size of the cell, what image size should I take ?

The height should be the distance from the top edge of a line to the top edge of the next line. The width should be the distance from the left edge of a line to the left edge of the next line.

> How to make it be repetitive so it would look nice ?

```
background-repeat: repeat; /* this is the default */
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned that javascript input is welcome, I'll add that you could use javascript to draw on a background canvas.

[jQuery Background Canvas Plugin](http://www.maierhofer.de/en/open-source/jquery-background-canvas-plugin.aspx)

[Mozilla.org Canvas Tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial)

[w3.org Canvas API](http://dev.w3.org/html5/canvas-api/canvas-2d-api.html)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, no way other than using **background images**. Possibly there is support of that in future versions of CSS though.

Comment: It seems too specific for the css folks to have made an exception -just- for that type of displaying, so I would expect images to be the only solution into the forseeable future.

Comment: @Tchalvak: Possibly but no ones knows about the future. Did we ever think about great functionality offered by CSS3 and HTML5 :)

Comment: Right, I'm extrapolating from stuff like that, the innovations in html5 & css3 are good because they're useful for a wide variety of use cases, because they're pretty generally applicable.  e.g. http://www.css3.info/preview/border-image/ is a single implementation with a multitude of uses because it's a general solution that can be used in version specific ways.  Same thing with the candystripe image, I expect.